# Dask and best practices with multiple indices

Tags: python, indexing, dask, dask-dataframe

It looks like I'm missing something quite fundamental about how DataFrame indices should be used in Dask.

I have a DataFrame in which most of the sorting and filtering is done on the column `date`, so following

https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html

specifically

> Dask DataFrame can be optionally sorted along a single index column.
> Some operations against this column can be very fast. For example, if
> your dataset is sorted by time, you can quickly select data for a
> particular day, perform time series joins, etc.

I decided to set the index to `date`. I was quite puzzled about whether having multiple indices with the same value (i.e. multiple observations at the same exact date) would constitute a problem, but the documentation hinted at the opposite and I didn't see any warning against repeated indices, I went on and reindexed my DataFrame with

```
cur_df = cur_df.set_index('date', sorted=True)
```

Then I needed to create a new column and I did it with

```
to_date_diff = lambda x : (x - cur_date).days/365
to_date_diff_meta = pd.Series([], dtype=float,  name='date_diff')
cur_df['date_diff'] = cur_df['final_date'].apply(to_date_diff, meta=to_date_diff_meta).compute()
```

but I got the error

```
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

So do I have to reindex everything now? Geeez! I wish I knew before reindexing all my DataFrames! What if I still want to perform "very fast" operations against the column "date" but it can't be the index because it has repeated values?

=== EDIT ===

My bad, I realized that the problem wasn't the index but the `.compute()` on my last line.

Still, the question remains:
Should I reindex my DataFrame (having unique indices? I'm not even sure unique indices are a thing in Dask since different partitions would reset their indices starting always from 0) or not (having the somehow disturbing multiple indices)?
I hope it's specified somewhere, I just couldn't find any clear hint in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case with this kind of problem, you may find it easier to operate with the map_partitions function to encapsulate your pandas operations in a single step

```
def map_me(df):
    to_date_diff = lambda x : (x - cur_date).days/365
    df['date_diff'] = df['final_date'].apply(to_date_diff)
    return df

out = cur_df.map_partitions(map_me, meta=...)
```

where providing a `meta` is optional.

Comment: Shouldn't we also have a `return df` statement in `map_me`?

Comment: quite right :) Always feel free to edit.